# need to get the count of users between a datetime range

Tags: sql

I need to create a report, which displays the number of users logged in for the time range provided by user. this seems to be a little complex for me as i am a newbee.
we need to count the users logged in between the hours for the time range selected

```
id,startdate,           enddate
1  01012018:14:01:10   01012018:15:30:40
1  01012018:16:11:50   01012018:16:30:45
2  01012018:09:41:50   01012018:16:30:45
1  01012018:09:41:50   01012018:10:30:45
2  01012018:19:41:50   01012018:21:30:45
3  01012018:09:31:10   01012018:21:20:45
```

The expected output:

```
startdate enddate  hours     total users logged
01012018  01012018 09-10
01012018  01012018 10-11
01012018  01012018 11-12
01012018  01012018 13-14 
01012018  01012018 14-15         01
01012018  01012018 15-16         01
01012018  01012018 16-17         01
01012018  01012018 17-18         01
01012018  01012018 18-19         01
01012018  01012018 19-20         01
01012018  01012018 20-21         01
01012018  01012018 21-22         01
01012018  01012018 22-23         
01012018  01012018 23-00
```

Comment: [so] is *not* a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a **[mcve]**. I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour].

Comment: Not clear how you get those numbers.  You have nothing for 09.

Comment: oops, i m sorry i missed it to mention the count for the hour 9-10

Comment: 2  01012018:09:41:50   01012018:16:30:45
1  01012018:09:41:50   01012018:10:30:45 we have users logged for the hours 9-10 or from 9-17.00

Comment: All timespans table, outer join, group by...

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. To help answer we need to know things like the types of these columns. They appear to be text. Showing us the schemas of your tables would help.

Comment: Shouldn't `01012018:09:41:50   01012018:16:30:45` count as a user logged in for all hours between 9-10 and 16-17?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be storing dates and times as text. That means you can't use Postgres's built in date functions to do the comparison. And you've stored them in a difficult to use format, "DDMMYYYY" or possibly "MMDDYYYY" is ambiguous and it needs to be parsed in order to sort it. Unless you have a good reason otherwise, stick to [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) for dates. Everything understands it and it sorts easily.

Your table should look something like this.

```
create table account_logins (
    id          serial primary key,
    account     integer not null references accounts(id),
    start_at    timestamp not null,
    end_at      timestamp not null
);
```

Every entry has its own id, just good practice. The account is declared as a proper foreign key.  And it's using the [`timestamp` type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/datatype-datetime.html) which means we can use [all the Postgres date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html). Finally, I've named them `start_at` and `end_at` because they are timestamps, not dates. `foo_at` is a naming convention that many systems use for timestamps.

And here's enough data to test it.

```
 id | account |      start_at      |       end_at       
----+---------+---------------------+---------------------
  1 |       1 | 2018-01-01 14:01:10 | 2018-01-01 15:30:40
  2 |       1 | 2018-01-01 16:11:50 | 2018-01-01 16:30:45
  3 |       2 | 2018-01-01 16:13:45 | 2018-01-01 16:25:11
```

What we want is something like this.

```
hour  | num_logins
------+-----------
...   | 0
13:00 | 0
14:00 | 1
15:00 | 1
16:00 | 2
17:00 | 0
...   | 0
```

Now that our schema is in better shape, we can start building up the query. First we need all the hours between 9am and midnight. We can do that with [`generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-srf.html).

```
select hour
from generate_series(
    '20180101 09:00'::timestamp,
    '20180101 23:00'::timestamp,
    '1 hour'
) as series(hour);
```

That gives us a list of hours to work with.

```
        hour         
---------------------
 2018-01-01 09:00:00
 2018-01-01 10:00:00
 2018-01-01 11:00:00
 2018-01-01 12:00:00
 2018-01-01 13:00:00
 2018-01-01 14:00:00
 2018-01-01 15:00:00
 2018-01-01 16:00:00
 2018-01-01 17:00:00
 2018-01-01 18:00:00
 2018-01-01 19:00:00
 2018-01-01 20:00:00
 2018-01-01 21:00:00
 2018-01-01 22:00:00
 2018-01-01 23:00:00
```

`as series(hour)` gives the generated table a name, `series`, and also the column, `hour`. This will make it easier to refer to shortly.

Now we join that series of hours with `account_logins` by checking which logins are within the `hour`...`hour+1` range.

```
select hour, id
from generate_series(
    '20180101 09:00'::timestamp,
    '20180101 23:00'::timestamp,
    '1 hour'
) as series(hour)
left outer join account_logins
    on start_at < hour+'1 hour' and hour < end_at;
```

`left outer join` ensures that every hour in the `series` is selected even if there's no logins for that hour. See [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/33052/visual-representation-of-sql-joins) for a fantastic understanding of the various joins.

That gives us this.

```
        hour         | id 
---------------------+----
 2018-01-01 09:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 11:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 12:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 |  1
 2018-01-01 15:00:00 |  1
 2018-01-01 16:00:00 |  2
 2018-01-01 16:00:00 |  3
 2018-01-01 17:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 18:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 19:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 21:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 22:00:00 |   
 2018-01-01 23:00:00 |
```

We can see the first login was counted for both hours it spans, and 16:00 has two logins.

The final step is to group the hours together, `group by hour`, count the number of logins in each hour, `count(id)`, and make sure they come out in the right order, `order by hour`.

```
select hour, count(id) as "total users logged"
from generate_series(
    '20180101 09:00'::timestamp,
    '20180101 23:00'::timestamp,
    '1 hour'
) as series(hour)
left outer join account_logins
    on start_at < hour+'1 hour' and hour < end_at
group by hour
order by hour;
```

And there you have it.

```
        hour         | total users logged 
---------------------+--------------------
 2018-01-01 09:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 10:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 11:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 12:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 13:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 14:00:00 |                  1
 2018-01-01 15:00:00 |                  1
 2018-01-01 16:00:00 |                  2
 2018-01-01 17:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 18:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 19:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 20:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 21:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 22:00:00 |                  0
 2018-01-01 23:00:00 |                  0
```

You can use [various date functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-datetime.html) to get the formatting just how you want, but I recommend keeping the query simple and generic. Instead, let whatever is consuming and displaying this data format it. Separate the formatting from the functionality.